# Understanding this bit of ASM code

Tags: assembly, x86

I've spent the past day or two delving into Assembly. I've been reading a rather good tutorial, and it's covered the different registers/how the binary number system works, etc; however, it doesn't really go into the Assembly code itself. It just talks about the concept of Assembly and how it works, etc (it does provide a few code examples, like the one below - but without explaining a lot of what's going on in the code).

```
msg db 'Displaying 9 stars', 0xa
len equ $ - msg
s2 times 9 db '*'
```

Although I feel I'm getting to know how things work, I'd like to ask a few questions regarding the above code (really want to understand how it works rather than accept the fact it works).

1) Can any text go after 0xa (I assume 0xa is a new-line)?

2) Does **$ - VARIABLE** (in this case, *$ - msg*) get the length of a variable? What's really the purpose of the $?

3) What is happening here: *s2 times 9 db '*'*

My assumption in Question #3 is that the variable s2 is just being set to a string of 9 *. If so, why does the db '*' come last? Wouldn't it make more sense to do s2 db '*' times 9

Comment: Assembly for which chip? x86? Which one?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Intel processor, x86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) sure, you could have e.g. a second and third line, and so on.

2) yes. $ means the current position, so $ - variable means current address minus start address of variable, i.e. the length.

3) nine data bytes are allocated from the current segment each with a character value of '*', the address given the name s2.

Comment: Ah, thank you. It looked like s2 was a part of the TIMES function.